# Making 'file' input element mandatory (required)

Tags: html, css

I want to make (an HTML) 'file' input element mandatory: something like

```
<input type='file' required = 'required' .../>
```

But it is not working.

I saw this [WW3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.file.html#input.file.attrs.required) manual which states 'required' attribute is new to HTML 5. But I am not using HTML 5 in the project I am working which doesn't support the new feature.

Any idea?

Comment: You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha javascript option is also good. Please tell.

Comment: Please provide more of the HTML file. I assume you have a submit button somewhere? Attach a javascript function that asserts whether or not the file input field is empty or not, and if empty then return an error message.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I did there first. Sorry for not finding one!!

Comment: @Bere yeah, it wasn't as easy as I initially assumed. It seems this may not have been asked yet (which is a rarity these days on Stack Overflow :)

Comment: why are you not using jQuery validation plugin..?

Answer (score 35):

**Thanks to HTML5, it is as easy as this:**

```
<input type='file' required />
```

**Example:**

```html
<form>
  <input type='file' required />
  <button type="submit"> Submit </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 11):

You can do it using Jquery like this:-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#upload').bind("click",function() 
    { 
        var imgVal = $('#uploadfile').val(); 
        if(imgVal=='') 
        { 
            alert("empty input file"); 
            return false; 
        } 


    }); 
});
</script> 

<input type="file" name="image" id="uploadfile" size="30" /> 
<input type="submit" name="upload" id="upload"  class="send_upload" value="upload" />
```

Comment: Thanks. But the form is a complex one. I want my solution to be as independent from any other (form) element as possible. I don't want to use(bind it with) the 'submit' button (or any of its attributes). Is there any other way?

Comment: Can you post the form structure ?

Comment: The elements and their attributes are defined in Joomla XML file. The form elements names and ids are changed/manipulated by the CMS before it is displayed. I am afraid if someone changes the name of the referred form element in the XML, completely different name/id pair may be generated. As a result I may lose the connection. I at least want the element becomes independent from specifically relying other form element.

Answer (score 11):

As of now in 2017, I am able to do this-

```
<input type='file' required />
```

and when you submit the form, it asks for file.
[image: Screenshot on Google Chrome]

Comment: I like the idea but this has no effect in my case (form in Laravel). Unfortunately :/

Comment: @daneczech probably you have not wrap it up with a `<form>` tag in your `html`

Answer (score 6):

You could create a polyfill that executes on the form submit. For example:

```
/* Attach the form event when jQuery loads. */
$(document).ready(function(e){

/* Handle any form's submit event. */
    $("form").submit(function(e){

        e.preventDefault();                 /* Stop the form from submitting immediately. */
        var continueInvoke = true;          /* Variable used to avoid $(this) scope confusion with .each() function. */

        /* Loop through each form element that has the required="" attribute. */
        $("form input[required]").each(function(){

            /* If the element has no value. */
            if($(this).val() == ""){
                continueInvoke = false;     /* Set the variable to false, to indicate that the form should not be submited. */
            }

        });

        /* Read the variable. Detect any items with no value. */
        if(continueInvoke == true){
            $(this).submit();               /* Submit the form. */
        }

    });

});
```

This script waits for the form to be submitted, then loops though each form element that has the `required` attribute has a value entered. If everything has a value, it submits the form.

An example element to be checked could be:

```
<input type="file" name="file_input" required="true" />
```

(You can remove the comments & minify this code when using it on your website)

Answer (score 4):

```
var imgVal = $('[type=file]').val();
```

Similar to Vivek's suggestion, but now you have a more generic selector of the input file and you don't rely on specific ID or class.

[**See this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/7GQjL/).

Comment: This is not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @Pere The demo seems to be an answer to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Some times the input field is not bound with the form.
I might seem within the `<form> and </form>` tags but it is outside these tags.

You can try applying the form attribute to the input field to make sure it is related to your form.

```
<input type="file" name="" required=""  form="YOUR-FORM-ID-HERE"  />
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

All statements above are entirely correct. However, it is possible for a malicious user to send a POST request without using your form in order to generate errors. Thus, HTML and JS, while offering a user-friendly approach, will not prevent these sorts of attacks. To do  so, make sure that your server double checks request data to make sure nothing is empty.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/form-required-attribute-with-a-custom-validation-message-in-html5/

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button> 


<p id="geeks"></p> 

<script> 
    function myFunction() { 
        var inpObj = document.getElementById("gfg"); 
        if (!inpObj.checkValidity()) { 
            document.getElementById("geeks") 
                    .innerHTML = inpObj.validationMessage; 
        } else { 
            document.getElementById("geeks") 
                    .innerHTML = "Input is ALL RIGHT"; 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you reply to a question, please explain your answer a little bit. In this case, there are 6 more answers, so you should expose the Pros of yours.