# Grails Client Side Form Validation

Tags: grails

if I click the submit button without picking a file, the form will still submit to the **upload** action.  For Grails, would you teach me how to validate **myFile** to make sure **myFile** is not empty before the form submit to the **upload** action please?

Thanks!

```
<g:uploadForm name="uploadForm1" action="upload">
   <input type="file" name="myFile" />
   <input class="save" type="submit" value="Import" />
</g:uploadForm>
```

Comment: Try this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17649479/making-file-input-element-mandatory-required).

Comment: Do you want the submit button disabled until a file is selected?  Would you prefer it be enabled but when you click it an error message is displayed if no file is selected?

Comment: This is a little bit more of a newbie Grails workflow question.  I am transitioning from PHP/JQuery to Grails.  I need to type all the JQuery javascript codes in the PHP and JS files to do the client side validation.  In Grails, do I also mix the gsp codes with javascript codes in the View and in the application.js file?  or I use some Grails function/tag to generate the client side javascript codes?  So, I don't have to type like I used to do in PHP?  Thanks!