# Make custom file upload angular component required in the form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have created a custom file upload angular component and I am using it in a template driven form. The form contains angular material components. I want this custom component to be required with the template driven form.

This is the html code for the custom component:

```
<input type="file" class="file-input" (change)="onFileSelected($event.target.files[0])" #fileUpload>
<div class="file-upload">
    <button type="button" mat-mini-fab color="primary" class="upload-btn" (click)="fileUpload.click()">
        <mat-icon>attach_file</mat-icon>
    </button>
    {{uploadedFileName || "Choose a file."}}
</div>
```

The typescript code:

```
uploadedFileName = "";

  @Output() onUploadFileEvent = new EventEmitter<File>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onFileSelected(uploadedFile: File) {
    if (uploadedFile) {
      this.uploadedFileName = uploadedFile.name;
      this.onUploadFileEvent.emit(uploadedFile);
    }
  }
```

And I am using the component like this in the form:

```
<app-file-uploader (onUploadFileEvent)="uploadFile($event)"></app-file-uploader>
```

How can I make this custom component required and prevent the user from submitting the form if a file is not yet selected ?

Thanks;

Comment: have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46575954/14392422)

Comment: It changes nothing, adding only the required attribute will not prevent form submission

Comment: You could have app-file-uploader implement MatFormFieldControl